# Java URL text file to String

Tags: java, string, file, url, text

I've hosted a text file which I would like to load into a string using java.

My code doesn't seem to work producing errors, any help?

```
try {
    dictionaryUrl = new URL("http://pluginstudios.co.uk/resources/studios/games/hangman/dictionary.dic");
} catch (MalformedURLException catchMalformedURLException) {
    System.err.println("Error 3: Malformed URL exception.\n"
                     + "         Dictionary failed to load.");
}
// 'Dictionary' scanner setting to file
// 'src/Main/Dictionary.dic'
DictionaryS = new Scanner(new File(dictionaryUrl));
System.out.println("Default dictionary loaded.");
```

UPDATE 1: The file doesn't seem to load going to the catch. But the file exists.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `FileInputStream` to read from a file? Also, can't you use `File` just for files in your local file system?

Comment: I'm having problems with reading local files, it works fine in NetBeans, but after building it, the .jar file doesn't seem to read the local files stored in the .jar file. Hence I'm trying to use a URL instead, I'm not sure how to use FileInputStream?

Comment: @KristianMatthews: you can't use `File` or `FileInputStream` for that matter, to load resources from your jar. Use `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` instead.

Comment: @stryba How does this work? My files are stored under src/Main/dictionary.txt

Comment: I don't know why you wanna load 2.4 mb of text file content into a String. It may take a long time. You should get the data with buffering.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something that [this tutorial does](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html)

```
   public class WebPageScanner {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
         URLConnection connection =
           new URL("http://java.net").openConnection();
         String text = new Scanner(
           connection.getInputStream()).
           useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
       } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: What's the useDelimiter("\\Z").next(); do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) and retrieve the data as a string or string buffer.
 then use parse or read as file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in your case:

```
DictionaryS = new Scanner(dictionaryUrl.openStream());
```

Comment: please be more specific, what didn't work, what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

JavaDoc tells us:

> File(URI uri)
>
> Creates a new File instance by converting the given file: URI into an abstract pathname.

We can't create and use a `File` instance for any other resource type (like `http`).